# for loop in r; number at the end of variable names

Tags: r, for-loop, mongolite

I have made 4 variables that represents 4 collections: zk1, zk2, zk3, zk4. Using mongolite:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  name <- paste0("zk", i, sep = "")
  collect <- paste0("zk", i, sep = "")
  assign(name, mongo(collection = collect, db = "zeko", url = "mongodb://localhost"))
}
```

Now, in next stages I would like to loop through variables when applying some method. I tried different ways but it always return an error. For example:

```
for (j in 1:length(zk_vector)) {
  j$count()
}
```

returns an error:

```
Error in j$count : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried other solutions but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval(parse(text = paste0(name,"$count")))`. You should check that `name` is in your environment and that you can access `realnamehere$count`. I assume it is not a function`count()`

Comment: I is a method count(). If I try your solution it gives me the description of the function.

Comment: I think there is some misconception about variables and functions. But I can only help you with a reproducable example: Please read [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) How to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R.